# Null reference exception is thrown when accessing property which is initialized using startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC6.

I have class named as **Commons.cs**.

In commons.cs i have property named as **key**, which is being initialized using startup.cs and appsettings.

**The problem is that:** I have one methods **Set()** which also resides in commons.cs and uses **key**.

But when I run the project **key's** value is null and gives error.

**I have tried this:**

Created one more class with property named as key1, and in default constructor assigned value to key1 as:

`public TempClass()
    {
      key1=Commons.Key;
    }`

and then i refer this key1 to the **Commons.Set()**.

Instead of this it gives null;

Summary: How to access startup.cs initialized properties throughout project.
or when the startup.cs actually initializes class properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is not much to work with in your question, I'll assume the properties your trying to access are static.

Try initializing them in a static constructor:

```
static Commons()
{
    Key = "Foo";
}
```

Comment: Ya its static. But I am passing it from the same class to the parameterised constructor of another class.

Comment: Did you verified your key field is initialized?
Are you calling the Set method after it is initialized?